# Theme copyWith not changing brightness

Tags: flutter

I have two differents flavors with differents styles, and Im trying to init MaterialApp copying this theme and change the brightness to dark or light depending of the settings states, but seems thaht copyWith is not working properly, because the brightness does not changes.

Here is the code:

```
return MaterialApp(
      theme: FlavorConfig.instance.theme.copyWith(
        brightness:
        Provider.of<SettingsViewModel>(context).darkModeEnabled
            ? Brightness.dark
            : Brightness.light,
      ),
```

Any idea?

Comment: The problem should be more how you are seting the theme in your application than the `copyWith` method. Can you add more code. (Your `MaterialApp` widget, where you are calling this method with the `return`, and the complete method)?

Comment: You can try it, if i change the primary color in the copyWith it works, but no if changing the brightness

Answer (score 0):

Try the `cupertinoOverrideTheme` attribute of the `Theme` white the `copyWith`
Something like:

```
return MaterialApp(
      theme: FlavorConfig.instance.theme.copyWith(
        brightness:
        Provider.of<SettingsViewModel>(context).darkModeEnabled
            ? Brightness.dark
            : Brightness.light,
        cupertinoOverrideTheme: FlavorConfig.instance.theme.cupertinoThemeData.copyWith(
          brightness: Provider.of<SettingsViewModel>(context).darkModeEnabled
            ? Brightness.dark
            : Brightness.light,
        ),
      ),
```